# java character textfield validation

Tags: java

I want name textfield validation and I am using this code, what is not working perfectly.

```
Name_text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
          public void keyPressed(KeyEvent EVT){

            if(EVT.getKeyChar()>='a'&& EVT.getKeyChar()<='z'|| EVT.getKeyChar()>='A'&& EVT.getKeyChar()<='Z'|| EVT.getKeyChar()==8|| EVT.getKeyChar()==26){

            Name_text.setEditable(true);
            }
            else{

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "enter characters only");

            }
```

Comment: what is your requirement???? [a-zA-Z] or 26 or 8 (keychar)?

Comment: What are you doing, and what is the error?

Comment: Explain what the error is and what you need it to do: "not working perfectly" is a bad description of an error.

Answer (score 1):

You really should perform this type of validation using the [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) class, this is exactly what it's designed for.  If the user pastes text into the field or you use `setText`, you will not be notified of the change via the `KeyListener`

You could also check out [this](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for a number of examples

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to validate with this code :

```
        if (Character.isDigit(EVT.getKeyChar())) {
                Name_text.setEditable(true);
                Name_text.setText("");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "enter characters only");
            }
```

Edited by your comment.

Comment: I want name textfield validation and I am using this code, what it is not working perfectly.problem is that when i enter a numeric,dialog box appears and numeric is also entered into textfield

Comment: I have updated it according to your code.Your code missed some brackets.

Comment: i am not able to do this by documentfilter,,,,can u help me plz

Comment: what do you want? When enter a numeric,dialog box appears and numeric should not entered into textfield ?

Comment: i want both,when enter a numeric,dialog box appears and numeric should not entered into textfield.